# How do you predict values with neural network in R?

Tags: r, machine-learning, neural-network

I am trying to predict the AQI value given time, region type (0,1,2,3), whether its in an industrial area (0,1), and whether there is a major road in the area (0,1). I have over 350,000 pairs of data and have trained the neural network using the code below. So then how can I use it predict the new AQI given a time, region type, area, and rd input? Or am I not understanding purpose of the neural network? Thanks!

````
  normalize <- function(x) {
    return ((x - min(x)) / (max(x) - min(x)))
  }

  #(AQI, class, ind, rd, hour)
  data = read.csv("neural_data") 
  data <- subset(data, select=c(2:6))
  data = na.omit(data)

  ## creating training and testing data
  train <- data

  ## Scale the network
  train_ <- normalize(train)


  ## Create the NN
  library(neuralnet)
  nn <- neuralnet(AQI~hour+rd+ind+class,data=train_,hidden=c(2,1),linear.output=F, threshold = 0.01)
  plot(nn)```
````

Comment: Are you looking for `predict()`?

Comment: Yes I understand you have to use predict, but how is function formatted? That is, if I have a data frame with columns “hour”, “rd”, “ind”, and “class” (all the factors), do you simply just call predict(nn, testdf) ?

Answer (score 2):

you have a multi-class prediction. As @user2974951 mentioned, use predict. Below I add on to show you have to interpret the results. And to note, if your predictors are 0 or 1, normalizing them is not going to change anything (see your function normalize).

```
library(neuralnet)
set.seed(1111)

# training /testing data
trn <- sample(1:nrow(iris),100)
trainData <- iris[trn,]
testData <- iris[-trn,]

# before you fit, check what are the levels of the labels
# in your case should be 0,1,2,3
levels(iris$Species)
1] "setosa"     "versicolor" "virginica" 

# fit nn
nn <- neuralnet(Species ~ Petal.Length + Petal.Width,trainData , linear.output = FALSE)
# predictions
pred <- predict(nn,testData)
head(pred)
> head(pred)
   [,1]       [,2]         [,3]
3     1 0.10672416 1.855968e-61
5     1 0.10944693 1.214708e-60
8     1 0.11238864 8.835106e-60
9     1 0.10944693 1.214708e-60
```

As you can see from heading pred, these are probabilities, first column probability of being setosa (the first level of Species) and second being versicolor and so on.. Every row is an observation from trainData

We can get back the labels, and do a confusion matrix

```
pred_labels <- levels(testData$Species)[apply(pred,1,which.max)]
actual_labels <- testData$Species

table(pred_labels,actual_labels)
            actual_labels
pred_labels  setosa versicolor virginica
  setosa         16          0         0
  versicolor      0         18         0
  virginica       0          2        14
```